# Create a mock of a class in a different namespace in PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I want to create a mock of a class in a different namespace. I tried the following code

```
    $fake = $this->getMockClass( __NAMESPACE__ . '\FakeTestBlock', array(), array(), '\NewNameSpace\GlobalFakeTestBlock' );
```

But I am getting the following error

`` PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Parse error: parse error, expecting `"identifier (T_STRING)"' in /path/to/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Generator.php(335) : eval()'d code on line 1 ``

Is there a way to create the mock in a different namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment you can't specify a namespace in the mocked class.
Is an [open issue](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects/issues/134).

> The setMockClassName() method does not expect a namespace because
>   PHPUnit automatically creates mocks in the same namespace as the class
>   being mocked. We should probably add some validation here so you don't
>   see the PHP error, though.

In the github issue are discussed same workaround, check if something is good for you. However this (in the same namespace) don't make any errors:

```
public function testMockedNameSpace()
{
    $fake = $this
             ->getMockBuilder('Acme\DemoBundle\Tests\GlobalFakeTestBlock')
             ->setMockClassName('FakeTestBlock')
             ->getMock();

}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks. I kind of suspected this. Now I have to see if I can use any of the workarounds mentioned there.

Comment: Looks like that issue is now closed. So am I right in saying there is no way to use get_class in testable code if the class you are needing has namespaces in it? In my case, I'm wanting to check whether config is defined or not and the key of the config uses the class name... If that's not possible, that's a real bummer. It might be worth making another issue on PHPUnit requesting it.